# why does the fs in node run at the end even if it is declared at the top in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my routes directory I have users.js and index.js.
In my users.js file i have written a function to read files in my folder using ('fs').This function is written at the top but it always executes at the end.
Can anyone help me out with it?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ObjectID = require('mongoskin').ObjectId;
var BSON = require('mongoskin').BSONPure;
var Parser = require('node-dbf');
var sambaserver = require('smb2');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var DBF = require('stream-dbf');






function Queue() {
    this.dataStore = [];
    this.enqueue = enqueue;
    this.dequeue = dequeue;
    this.front = front;
    this.back = back;
    this.toString = toString;
    this.empty = empty;
}

function enqueue(element) {
    this.dataStore.push(element);
}
function dequeue(element) {
    return this.dataStore.shift();
}

function front() {
    return this.dataStore[0];
}

function back() {
    return this.dataStore[this.dataStore.length -1];
}



function toString() {
    var retstr = "";
    for (var i =0;i < this.dataStore.length;i++)
    {
        retstr += this.dataStore[i] + "\n";
    }
    return retstr;
}

function empty() {
    if(this.dataStore.length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


var q = new Queue ()








var p = "/home/admin/Documents/Project-name/public/folder/",


  currentFile;
fs.readdir(p, function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    files.map(function (file) {
        // return path.join(p, file);
        return path.join(p, file);
    }).filter(function (file) {
        return fs.statSync(file).isFile();
    }).forEach(function (file) {
        // console.log(file);
        q.enqueue(file);
        // console.log(file);
    });



for(var i = 0;i <= q.dataStore.length;i++)
{

currentFile = q.front();
var parser = new DBF(currentFile,true);
var stream = parser.stream;
     //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   stream.on('readable', function() {
  var record = stream.read();
  // do something with the record
   db1.collection('tempDBVis').insert(record, function(err,result){
        (err === null) ? {msg : delete1()} : {msg : console.log("error")};
        q.dequeue();
    });
}); 
stream.on('end', function() {
  console.log('finished');

});
function delete1() {
        fs.unlink(currentFile, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('successfully deleted FILE');
        });
    }

}

});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing a callback like so:

```
fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
    ...
});
```

then you are *executing* `readFile` which *immediately returns*, and your code continues.  The function you passed as the 2nd parameter to `readFile` is executed asynchronously by the `fs` package when it has completed reading the file - which is likely to be *after* the rest of your code has completed.

Asynchronous programming is awesome but can be confusing to start with.

```
var first = "this line executes first"

fs.readFile("test.json", function (err, data) {
    var third = "this line executes last"
    // The FS package has to read from the filesystem (spinning up the disc,
    // waiting on the operating system etc) and this may take several
    // milliseconds.  Rather than 'blocking' the rest of your code from
    // executing, the fs package IMMEDIATELY RETURNS from the 'readFile'
    // function and promises to call THIS CALLBACK FUNCTION at a later
    // time (when it has finished reading the file)
});

var second = "this line executes second"
```

Here is some code that may help point you in the right direction.  It can be broken down further (perhaps a `processItem` function?) but hopefully its a start.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var sys = require('sys');

var ObjectID = require('mongoskin').ObjectId;
var BSON = require('mongoskin').BSONPure;
var Parser = require('node-dbf');
var sambaserver = require('smb2');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var DBF = require('stream-dbf');






function Queue() {
    this.dataStore = [];
}

Queue.prototype = {
    enqueue: function (element) {
        this.dataStore.push(element);
    },

    dequeue: function (element) {
        var index;

        if (element) {
            index = this.dataStore.indexOf(element);
            if (index > -1) {
                return this.dataStore.splice(this.dataStore.indexOf(element))
            }
        }

        return this.dataStore.shift();
    },

    front: function () {
        return this.dataStore[0];
    },

    back: function () {
        return this.dataStore[this.dataStore.length -1];
    },

    toString: function () {
        return this.dataStore.join('\n');
    },

    empty: function () {
        return this.dataStore.length === 0;
    },

    size: function () {
        return this.dataStore.length;
    }
}











var queue = new Queue ();
var myPath = "/home/kesari-alnoorkhan/Documents/KesariReporting/public/DbfFiles2/";

fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;

    files.map(function (file) {
        return path.join(path, file);
    }).filter(function (file) {
        return fs.statSync(file).isFile();
    }).forEach(function (file) {
        queue.enqueue(file);
    });

    // Now that all the files have been read/filtered/enqueued, you can process them
    processRecords();
});


function processRecords () {
    var file;
    var parser;
    var stream;

    for (var i = 0, len = queue.size(); i < len; i++) {
        file = queue.front();
        parser = new DBF(file, true);
        stream = parser.stream;

        attachHandlersToStream(stream, file);
    }
}

function attachHandlersToStream(stream, file) {
    // Readable handler
    stream.on('readable', function () {
        var record = this.read();

        // what is "db1" ??  This is where you do whatever you want with the item
        db1.collection('tempDBVis').insert(record, function (err, result) {
            // this line here looks suspicious - what are you trying to do?
            //(err === null) ? {msg : delete1()} : {msg : console.log("error")};

            // something like this?
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error', err);
            }
            else {
                fs.unlink(file, function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    console.log('successfully deleted FILE');
                });
            }

            queue.dequeue(file);
        });
    });

    // End handler
    stream.on('end', function () {
        queue.dequeue(file);
        console.log('finished:', file);
    });
}











module.exports = router;
```

Comment: In the line `for(var i = 0;i <= q.dataStore.length;i++)` you are reading `q.dataStore.length` BEFORE anything has been added to the Queue, hence it will be 0 and the for loop will never be entered.

Comment: Your `for` loop is equivalent to `var second...` in my example, and you're adding items to your queue at `var third...` in my example.

Comment: how shall i add items and what modifications are required in code...Thanks for your help buddy

Comment: @user3791726 I have updated with an example using your code.  Follow it through and try to think about what is available in what scope.  Remember that asynchronous functions that take a callback (looks like `readFile(path, function () {`) will *immediately* return and begin executing your *next* line of code.

Comment: @user3791726 I've update the example.  If this has helped, can you please accept my answer?  Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

Node.js is an asynchronous env. So writing at top doesn't mean it'll run first. You could try fs.readFileAsync method instead of fs.readFile and that'll behave like you expect. But don't do this for large file reads as it'll cause performance problems.